# Different light fixture quit working after changing switch

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

Upstairs: I just replaced some halogen track lights with LEDs. The switches were double pole and are illuminated when the lights are off. This caused the LEDs to have a dim light even when they were turned off.

So, I decided to switch out both switches for some non-illuminated double pole switches that I had downstairs. Everything seemed fine, but after switching the breakers back on, two things changed:

1. One fixture (which shared a panel with one of the downstair switches) switched "direction". I'm almost positive that up used to be on, but now it's off when it's up. As far as I know, this is not a double pole switch.
2. A downstairs ceiling lamp with a pull switch quit working.

I'm more worried about fixing #2, but thought it was worth mentioning #1 in case it's related.

Comment: Is the fixture in #1 on a three-way switch?  Also, is the fixture on #2 on an always live circuit?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - For #1, I'm not sure, but I don't think so. There definitely isn't another switch. I don't know what an always live circuit is, so I can't answer your other question :)

Comment: "always live" means there's no other switch :)

Comment: Also, on #1 -- I take it the switch that controls that fixture was unfastened from the box?

Comment: For #1 - it was never unfastened. I totally left both #1 and #2 alone.

#2 is always live - there's only the pull switch. It's a light in the laundry room.

As another wrinkle to the situation - #2 came on for a little bit today, and then quit working again. No idea why. Should I get an electrician out?

Comment: An electrician is the order of the day for this situation. It is really hard to debug this from what what you have posted so far and it sounds like the electrical domain is not your area of expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI, the electrician came out and solved the problem - I had a loose wire in the upstairs switch which was breaking the circuit downstairs.

Comment: Hey, Jeremy, you're not new to SE. How about giving your answer a check mark (since it did solve the problem), so that it doesn't get more Community bumps. Thanks!